# Angular6, Cannot add new data

Tags: json, angular, jakarta-ee, angular6

I have an angular6 projet (front) with JavaEE (back): REst Api
When i try to add a new user , i have a problem with the date format.
This json format is accepted normally in my back-end and DB

```
 {

 "name":"some_name",
 "country":"some_country",
 "date":"2018-05-16",
 ...

 }
```

but the front sends a json of the format :

```
  {


  "name":"some_name",
  "country":"some_country",
  "date": {
     "date": {
       "year": 2018,
       "month": 6,
       "day": 9
         },
     "jsdate": "2018-06-08T22:00:00.000Z",
     "formatted": "06/09/2018",
       "epoc": 1528495200
     },
  ...

   }
```

i'm using this in my component.html

```
   <my-date-picker>
```

I'm a using Spring Framework, entitymanager.persist() method to add new object.
My question is : how can I modify my component so that he sends a correct date format.

Comment: change the date format to yyyy-mm-dd here is the documentation (https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker?files=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date=new Date(date.date.year ,date.date.month - 1,date.date.day);

var res = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + (date.getDate())).slice(-2);

console.log(res) 
//output yyyy-mm-dd
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may solve the problem at hand, more explanation is necessary to help future users of the site understand how to apply this solution to their situation.